# Can someone help to identify this insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found a few of these insects around my house, and I'm curious what insect it is.

- Seen mid-August in Singapore
- At least several mm but lest than 1 cm long
- Seen walking slowly. I can't be sure but don't think it can fly
- No sound noticed

[image]

Comment: For species identification questions it's necessary to include as much information as you can. Can you mention at least roughly your location on Earth? Also, can you estimate the approximate size of this insect? 1mm? 1 cm? What about behavior; was it flying, or walking, moving quickly or slowly? Did it make any noise? *Thanks!*

Comment: Singapore, less than 1cm, walking slowly, dont think it can fly, no noise. Appreciate your help thank you 